# Java - Anamorfismo (manipulação de imagem)

Tags: java, imagem, image

Boa noite, estou criando uma aplicação para um objetivo especifico, que manipule imagem, estou usando métodos como:

```
image.BufferedImage
Graphics2D
RenderingHints
```

Nesse contexto estou pegando uma imagem especifica por exemplo

[image]

Manipulando ela e transformando assim

[image]

Gerando um anamorfismo, no entanto estou fazendo da seguinte forma, rotacionando a imagem no angulo desejado, depois esticando lateralmente ela a proporção desejada e voltando ao angulo o original, por exemplo, essa rotacionei (40,0 graus) depois estiquei 20% e des-rotacionei (-40,0 graus), ai fica com esse efeito de anamorfismo e eu salvo a imagem na pasta desejada, queria saber se existe algum outro método que só colocando o angulo ele faça o anamorfismo sozinho sem todo esses trabalho?

> O que estou utilizando 
>   (BufferedImage resize)
>   (BufferedImage rotateMyImage)

```
 public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage img, String outputFileLocation, String extension){

    int new_largura = img.getWidth();
    int new_altura = img.getHeight();

    int mat = new_largura + ((new_largura *50)/100);
    new_largura = new_largura + mat;

    BufferedImage new_img;

    new_img = new BufferedImage(new_largura, new_altura, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D graphics2d = new_img.createGraphics();
    graphics2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, new_largura, new_altura, null);

    writeImage(new_img, outputFileLocation, "png");

    return img;
}


public static BufferedImage rotateMyImage(BufferedImage img, double angle, String outputFileLocation) {
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();
    int iw = w+200;
    int ih = h+200;
    BufferedImage dimg =new BufferedImage(iw, ih, img.getType());
    Graphics2D g = dimg.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, // Anti-alias!
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    g.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), iw/2, ih/2);

    // ensure image will fit
    int dw = w;
    int dh = h;
    if (dw > iw) {
        dh = (int)(dh * ( (float) iw / (float) dw)) ;
        dw = iw;
    }
    if (dh > ih) {
        dw = (int)(dw * ( (float) ih / (float) dh)) ;
        dh = ih;
    }
    // centre on page
    int dx = (iw - dw) / 2;
    int dy = (ih - dh) / 2;

    g.drawImage(img, dx, dy, dx+dw, dy+dh, 0, 0, w, h, null);

    writeImage(dimg, outputFileLocation, "png");

    //g.drawImage(img, null, 0, 0);
    return dimg;
}
```

OK funciona, mas preciso entrar em várias pastas desde a pasta 0-0, 0-1....0-4...até a pasta 10-10 e cada pasta tem 131 arquivos de imagem, cada pasta representa um angulo diferente a distorcer e fazer o anamorfismo e preciso pegar a imagem, fazer o anamorfismo e salva-la sobrepondo a original em cada imagem, são aproximadamente 14440 imagens, queria facilitar o processo pois está consumindo muito do computador dando erro de processamento antes de acabar, além de ser muito trabalho de laço (for) para que seja executado, queria saber se existe algum metodo para essa atividade?

Agradeço a ajuda de todos.